# kdb/q: How to concatenate adjacent elements in a list of strings with a space in between?

Tags: string, list, concatenation, kdb

Thank you in advance for the help!  (I am coming from a C++ and Python background, and not using while-loops in kdb has been hard for me)

In kdb/q, I have a list of strings, let's call it "test", which looks like this.  There are 7 entries in this list, and each entry is a string.  The entries (strings) at indices 2 and 4 are empty.

```
test
"col_1:abc col_2:xyz"
"col_3:ijk"
""
"col_1:efg col_2:lmn"
""
"col_1:bah"
"col_3:muy"
```

I want to concatenate adjacent entries together, so that it looks like this below.  The entries next to each other are joined together by a space, and the empty entries have disappeared

```
"col_1:abc col_2:xyz col_3:ijk"
"col_1:efg col_2:lmn"
"col_1:bah col_3:muy"
```

This is my best attempt so far.  I am sure that I am over-complicating it and there must be a better way.

```
show {$[x~"";"|";x]}each test
"col_1:abc col_2:xyz"
"col_3:ijk"
"|"
"col_1:efg col_2:lmn"
"|"
"col_1:bah"
"col_3:muy"

show raze {$[x~"";"|";x]}each test
"col_1:abc col_2:xyzcol_3:ijk|col_1:efg col_2:lmn|col_1:bahcol_3:muy"

show "|" vs raze {$[x~"";"|";x]} each test
"col_1:abc col_2:xyzcol_3:ijk"
"col_1:efg col_2:lmn"
"col_1:bahcol_3:muy"
```

I am close, but I don't have the desired space separating "col_2:xyz" from "col_3:ijk" at index 0 of the new list, and I don't have the space separating "col_1:bah" from "col_3:muy" at index 2 of the new list.  How to overcome this issue?  I really appreciate your pointers / hints, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Quick solution for case above where there are no consecutive empty strings

```
q)"  "vs" "sv test
"col_1:abc col_2:xyz col_3:ijk"
"col_1:efg col_2:lmn"
"col_1:bah col_3:muy"
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the quick and elegant solution!  I am learning a lot from you!

Answer (score 2):

If the list of strings is being read from a file, an alternative option would be to use `read1` to read the file as bytes, rather than `read0` to read as strings. e.g.

```
q)"  " vs {@[x;where x=0x0a;:;0x20]} read1`:test.txt
"col_1:abc col_2:xyz col_3:ijk"
"col_1:efg col_2:lmn"
"col_1:bah col_3:muy "
```

Here, we replace newlines (`0x0a`) with spaces (`0x20`), and then split on any double space (i.e. were there was before a blank line).

One caveat is that if file ends with a new line, last string has a trailing space (depending on how you're using the new list of strings, that might not matter but if it does, could drop that last char, or use `trim` to remove etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Your own approach would work like this:

```
q)trim"|"vs" "sv{$[x~"";1#"|";x]}each test
"col_1:abc col_2:xyz col_3:ijk"
"col_1:efg col_2:lmn"
"col_1:bah col_3:muy"
```

Here's an alternative which uses a `cut`

```
q){ltrim" "sv'cut[0,where""~/:x;x]}[test]
"col_1:abc col_2:xyz col_3:ijk"
"col_1:efg col_2:lmn"
"col_1:bah col_3:muy"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I understood the first example by running the code myself.  However, I can't figure out what you are doing with "cut" in the second solution.  I know that: where ""~/: x is essentially a loop that finds which entries in "test" have an empty char "" and returns the indices 2 & 4.  But what does the 0 in cut mean?  The only reference that I could find is here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cut/ which doesn't use a format of cut[0,arg1, arg2]

Comment: No worries. Firstly, the keyword `cut` behaves the same as `_` (cut) if `x` is not an integer atom, as mentioned at the bottom of that page. Secondly I needed the cut to begin at the start so I appended to zero to include the zero index. Take a look at the difference between `2 4 cut til 7` and `0 2 4 cut til 7`.

Comment: Oh, got it.  You are just adding 0 to the beginning of the list, so you cut using indices 0 2 4 instead of indices 2 4.  Thanks so much.